# Как грамотно составить MySQL запрос?

Tags: mysql, запрос-в-запросе, запрос

Добрый день!

Никак не могу понять, как лучше бы составить запрос. Есть у меня таблица такого вида:

---

```
|id | uid | referer |
| 1 |  2  | site.ru |
| 2 |  2  | my.ru/xxx |
| 3 |  2  | my.ru/yyy |
| 4 |  3  | xxx.ru |
| 5 |  4  | site.ru |
| 6 |  4  | my.ru |
```

---

Мне нужно выбрать все записи, uid которых пришли с сайта site.ru, т.е. должны выбраться строки с ID = 1,2,3,5,6.

Делал вложенный запрос такого вида:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE uid IN(SELECT uid FROM tbla WHERE referer LIKE "%site.ru%")
```

Но т.к. в таблице почти 2 млн записей, то такой запрос и за час не выполняется.
Индексами являются id и uid.

Подскажите, как можно более грамотно оптимизировать запрос?
Спасибо!

Comment: Очевидно, referer - должно быть, varchar с индексом и перестать использовать `LIKE`.

Comment: Нужно было подготавливать данные перед записью в базу. Например, вычленять домен и складывать его его в отдельное поле. А уже по этому полю строить индекс.

Comment: referer varchar. И это поле в большинстве случаев будет уникально.
Если перестать использовать LIKE то как мне выбрать записи типа site.ru/xxx, site.ru/yyy и.т.п?
Сам запрос SELECT uid FROM tbla WHERE referer LIKE "%site.ru%" выполняется довольно быстро, пару секунд. А вот с подзапросом висит

Comment: @Jeid, добавляй необходимое поле и делай как написал @dimka3210.

Comment: Тогда тоже гемор. Пользователь зашёл на сайт первый раз по ссылке с другого сайта. У него referer будет site.ru/xxx
Дальше он ходит уже по поему сайту и у него referer будет my.ru/zxc

Можно конечно по uid найти его первый заход и брать оттуда домен первоначальный, но когда на сайт одновременно заходит по несколько десятков человек и таблица весит 5 гб с более 20 мдн записей, то это тот еще пипец будет для базы.
@dimka3210 @VasyOk

Comment: @Jeid, план выполнения покажите. Индексы не используются, скорее всего, или данных много возвращается. Все может быть.

Comment: Решение @dimka3210, т.е. выделить из referer домен + добавить поле `domain_hash` с индексом (можно сделать первичным ключом), где будет храниться бинарный хэш от referer-домена. Если referer-домен не требуется где-либо отображать. то полностью отказаться от этого поля.

    |domain_hash | uid |

Об это можно почитать [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/a/504434) и [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/a/317906)

Comment: @Jeid К сведению:

 * [Макс. длина домена 254 символа](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/16997), т.е. `VARCHAR(255)`
 * [Макс. длина URL зависит от браузера](http://stackoverflow.com/a/417184), т.е. `TEXT`

Comment: @romeo, а кто мешает вам поставит [VARCHAR(21000)][1] ?


  [1]: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-type-overview.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Можно у поля referer сделать индекс, и зная что все referer начинаются одинаково искать используя индекс `SELECT uid FROM tbla WHERE referer LIKE "site.ru%"`  . Если поисковое слово в %% то индекс не используется.
2. Используйте полнотекстовый поиск. Если у вас движок MyISAM то создайте полнотекстовый индекс для поля referer и `SELECT uid FROM`tbla`WHERE MATCH(`referer`) AGAINST('site.ru')`

Answer (score 0):

Раз сам подзапрос SELECT uid FROM tbla WHERE referer LIKE "%site.ru%" выполняется довольно быстро, то у вас очевидно MySQL < 5.6 (MariaDB < 5.3)
Т.е. подзапрос выполняется для каждой строки основного. Перепишите через join

```
SELECT * FROM tbl JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT uid FROM tbla WHERE referer LIKE "%site.ru%") t using(uid);
```